# Getting and setting variables with .bat/cmd

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

How can i get the first output of the command `where python` and include all in the run.bat file ?

`where python` output:

```
C:\Users\Vermelhao>where python
C:\Program Files\Python\310\python.exe
C:\Users\Vermelhao\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Desired value "C:\Program Files\Python\310\python.exe"

`run.bat`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
"C:\Program Files\Python\310\python.exe" "./main.py"
pause
```

### I want to assemble the run.bat file in a way that the python.exe path comes from the first path returned by the `where python` command

i've tried using `set path=$(where python)` but this holds the value like a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where python` returns the first Python found in the PATH.  That is EXACTLY what you would get if you just ran `python` without specifying a path.  So, what you ask is **literally** the same thing as this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python ./main.py
pause
```